# A task has failed to un-serialize

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I keep getting the following error when I try to run some clustering algorithms:

> sklearn.externals.joblib.externals.loky.process_executor.BrokenProcessPool: A task has failed to un-serialize. Please ensure that the arguments of the function are all picklable.

I tried the following:

- Updating scikit-learn to 0.20.2
- Changing n_jobs = 1 and -1

  ```
  grid = {'km__n_clusters': self._clusters, 'NN__alpha': self._nn_reg, 'NN__hidden_layer_sizes': self._nn_arch}
  mlp = MLPClassifier(activation='relu', max_iter=2000, early_stopping=True, random_state=self._details.seed)
  km = kmeans(random_state=self._details.seed, n_jobs=self._details.threads) #tried n_jobs=self._details.threads
  pipe = Pipeline([('km', km), ('NN', mlp)], memory=experiments.pipeline_memory)
  gs, _ = self.gs_with_best_estimator(pipe, grid, type='kmeans')
  self.log("KMmeans Grid search complete")
  ```

Comment: *Where exactly* does the error pop up?? Please post the complete error trace (text, no images).